# Automating a PHP Upload process on a website (local drive to online server)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ftp

I have a file on my local drive that I need to upload to my online server.

The file name will always be helloWorld.log and will always be located at the same location i.e. C:\TestFile.

Local file location: C:\TestFile\helloWorld.log (this file could be a .json or other type if that helps)

Content in the file (helloWorld.log) is JSON Object i.e. {"time":"1.15", "height":"3"}

The content in the file is updated every 5 seconds, and this is why I need to upload the file to the server every 5 seconds, to extract info for my use.

What I thought of was to somehow automate the following php process... I may be am completely wrong and that's why I am here... Wondering, if I can somehow hard-code the location of the file, name, type and/or other pertinent characteristics needed for uploading a file and refreshing the UploadButton to imitate the clicking action every 4.5 seconds or whatever it takes to match with the 5 seconds file update...

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (isset($name)) {
    if (!empty ($name)) {            
        $location = "uploadFile_23-Jun-2014/";

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'uploaded';
        }
    }
}

?>

<div class="hidden">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"  />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

So, this is what I have in mind and if someone could help me automate this process, that would be amazing. I have looked into JS/jQuery and other client side scripting and none are truly client side enabled (as you experts would have experienced). I really don't want to learn another language to accomplish this, I want to keep it in JS/PHP realm.

I am certain there may available other FTP'ing options, but I have ran into none that made sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://superuser.com/a/188554 ?

Comment: Hi denoir, I think the product you mentioned has been recommended for backup, type of operation. I have a much frequent operation in place. Thank you for trying to help, however.

Comment: What are you using to update the file locally? Does the file need to be updated locally? I think it's more common to update the file by FTP, and then have your PHP app look for the changes on its own server.

Comment: Hi Ross, I am updating the local file directly (data generating device wired to my PC). I am trying to write a php code to directly FTP from my PC to my server. I'm still in the process writing that, so I haven't tested it yet. Perhaps, I can get a working FTP code that I can use to directly FTP my file to my server. If you have any idea, or anything for that matter, I am all ears. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to connect to my server via the following FTP method (from php.net), and was unsuccessful. Will this method fail when attempting to connect to shared hosting services with godaddy? Any help would be appreciated. 

<?php
                     
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_user = "foo";
$ftp_pass = "bar";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>